# Is jqTouch incompatible with jquery.colorbox.js?

Tags: javascript, colorbox, jqtouch

I'm develping web app which contains jqtouch and jquery.colorbox.js (both included in root html). It looks like those two files are incompatible - javascript execution fails without error.

Is anyone familiar with this problem? What would be soloution to this problem?

best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found soloution!

I have to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" />
```

to root HTML after executing

var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
    ...

and now it works fine!